# Native Query INSERT is giving ERROR : Method is only allowed for a Query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am currently working on a SpringBoot + Hibernate project.
I have a requirement to Insert few values to a DB.

I am trying to achieve this using Native Query. Below is my Code :

```
@Repository
public interface StoreDataRepository extends JpaRepository<StoreDataRepository, Long> {

    @Query(value ="insert into store (id, name) values(:id, :name)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void storeData(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name);
```

From my Service, I am just calling this method with id and name parameters.

But I am getting the below error :

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Method only for queries
```

Can you please assist me with this ?

Comment: If using Spring, add `@Modifying` as documented here: [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation - 4.3.8. Modifying queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries)

Comment: Hi Andreas - Yes I tried using the @Modifying but then I get an error such as : javax.persistence.TransactioRequiedException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: So why aren't you in a transaction when doing updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the above issue.

I had to specify @Transactional and @Modifying to my Repository method.

Below solved the issue.

```
@Repository
public interface StoreDataRepository extends JpaRepository<StoreDataRepository, Long> {

    @Trsansactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value ="insert into store (id, name) values(:id, :name)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void storeData(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name);
```